# Java code for Importing git project from local in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, git, eclipse-plugin, egit

We follow the below steps to import a Local Git project in Eclipse:

**File** -> **Import** -> **Git** -> **Projects From Git** > **Existing local repository**

How can we achieve the same using a Java program?

I used `org.eclipse.core.resources` to import the project by giving the path of a `.project` file but it doesn't give Git connectivity.

```java
IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();
IWorkspaceRoot root = workspace.getRoot();
IProject project = root.getProject("myProject/.project"); // path to .project file
project.create(new NullProgressMonitor());
project.open(null);
```

I also went through [JGit Docs](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/site/4.8.0.201706111038-r/apidocs/index.html), but didn't find any solution

Comment: If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older posts which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 1):

In order to load a project into the Eclipse workspace, you need to load the project description (stored in the .project file) first. Once you have an IProjectDescription instance, you can use it to create it, i.e. make it known to the Eclipse workspace.

For example:

```java
IProjectDescription description = workspace.loadProjectDescription( "path/to/.project" );
IProject project = workspace.getRoot().getProject( description.getName() );
project.create( description, new NullProgressMonitor() );
project.open( new NullProgressMonitor() );
```

In order to check whether a project of the same name is already known to the workspace, use this code:

```java
workspace.getRoot().getProject( description.getName() );
```

If the repository to which the project to be imported belongs is not yet known to Egit, you need to register the repository first:

```java
RepositoryUtil.addConfiguredRepository( new File( "path/to/.git-dir" ) );
```

Then you can use Egit's `ConnectProviderOperation` to mark the workspace project as part of the registered repository:

```java
IEGitOperation operation = new ConnectProviderOperation( project, "path/to/.git-dir" );
operation.execute( new NullProgressMonitor() );
```

All Egit types discussed here can be found in the `org.eclipse.egit.core` plug-in.

Comment: Your first code for project creation helped me. After that I need to modify the workspace rulefactory to get project content and git connectivity using `workspace.getRuleFactory().modifyRule()`

Comment: Don't understand what 'need to modify the workspace rulefactory' means. Are you asking which rule to use to connect a project to a repository?

Comment: I mean, I was able to solve the problem by calling `workspace.getRuleFactory().modifyRule()` after  `project.open`

Comment: `modifyRule()` just returns a rule to modify the given resource. It is unlikely that this method call solves anything to do with creating a project. If you are interested in a reliable solution, you should remove the `modifyRule()` call and investigate why creating the project does not work (if so).